# Renaming and moving files in a subdirectory with an index and the folder name

Tags: bash, directory

I'm putting together a script to take .mp4 files organized into folders that described the video (eg. cat) and I'd like to do the following:

1. rename them with the folder name and a number
2. move the video into a folder named and numbered in the same manner
3. parse the video into frames using ffmpeg

I'm posting this here to be a reference for others and to ask about how this could be done better.  It works fine but I'm wondering how to make it better.

```
for dir in /path/to/parent/directory/*; do
cd "$dir" && result=${PWD##*/} 
cd video
echo "$result"
a=1
    for i in *.mp4; do
        dafile="$(printf "_%02d.mp4" ${a})" 
        dafolder="$(printf "_%02d" ${a})"
        newfolder="$result$dafolder"
        newfile="$result$dafile"
        mkdir "${newfolder}"
        mv "${i}" "${newfolder}/${newfile}"

        cd "${newfolder}"
            ffmpeg -i "${newfile}" -r 30 -f image2 "${newfolder}-\%04d.png"
        cd ..
        let a=a+1
    done

done
```

I used the following links to figure out a bunch of ideas for the code:

- [Get current directory name without full path in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script)
- [Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Quite nicely done! I only have a few minor comments.

The script is not very "safe" as it is.
There are many possible failure points which are ignored:

- What if `/path/to/parent/directory/*` doesn't exist?
- What if `cd "$dir"` fails? (`$dir` is not really a directory, or you don't have permission to enter it)
- What if `cd video` fails? (Like `$dir`)
- What if `*.mp4` doesn't exist?
- What if `mkdir "${newfolder}"` fails? (no permission)

If any of the above happens, 
the script will continue to run regardless of any errors,
and potentially create junk files and directories you didn't intend.

Here's a safer way to protect against these failures:

```
for dir in /path/to/parent/directory/*; do
    cd "$dir" || continue
    result=${PWD##*/} 
    cd video || continue
    echo "$result"
    a=1
    for i in *.mp4; do
        test -f "$i" || continue
        dafile="$(printf "_%02d.mp4" ${a})" 
        dafolder="$(printf "_%02d" ${a})"
        newfolder="$result$dafolder"
        newfile="$result$dafile"
        mkdir "${newfolder}" || continue
        mv "${i}" "${newfolder}/${newfile}"
        cd "${newfolder}"
        ffmpeg -i "${newfile}" -r 30 -f image2 "${newfolder}-\%04d.png"
        cd ..
        ((a++))
    done
done
```

I also fixed the indentation, and replaced `let a=a+1` with the somewhat simpler and more intuitive `((a++))`.

You seem to like `${name}` instead of `$name`. That's fine, but it's not needed anywhere in the posted code. Usually it's needed in situations like `${name}_suffix`, where without the `${...}` the "_suffix" would become part of the variable name.

Comment: Ahhh ... nice. I haven't used logic / continue with bash yet.  Good fix. 

So in the case of 'cd video || continue', if a directory labeled 'video' exists, then it will continue to the next line and won't execute the command continue that jumps to the next iteration of the loop because || is the 'or' operator.  

In contrast, if I used 'cd video && continue', it would jump out of that loop **if** there is a directory called video.  

And similarly, 'cd video || break' would stop the loop and not perform any more iterations.

Comment: Yes, like that!